# why I am getting runtime error in this code

Tags: c++

I debuged this and I found that it occurring because of `v3.size()` in last for loop, outside loop value of `v3.size()` is `0`, while inside the loop value is 18076382629293 something like this. why ?

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;

  cin >> n;
  vector<vector<int>> v;
  int a, b, c;

  map<vector<int>, int> m;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    vector<int> v1;
    v1.push_back(a);
    v1.push_back(b);
    v1.push_back(c);
    m[v1] = i + 1;
    v.push_back(v1);
    // cout << 1;
  }
  sort(v.begin(), v.end());

  // int j = i;
  vector<vector<int>> v2;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == n - 1) {
      v2.push_back(v[i]);
      continue;
    }
    if (v[i][0] == v[i + 1][0]) {
      if (v[i][1] == v[i + 1][1]) {
        cout << m[v[i]] << " " << m[v[i + 1]] << endl;
        i++;
        continue;
      }
    }
    v2.push_back(v[i]);
  }

  vector<vector<int>> v3;
  for (int i = 0; i < v2.size(); i++) {
    if (i == v2.size() - 1) {
      v3.push_back(v2[i]);
      continue;
    }
    if (v2[i][0] == v2[i + 1][0]) {
      cout << m[v2[i]] << " " << m[v2[i + 1]] << endl;
      i++;
      continue;
    }
    v3.push_back(v2[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < v3.size() - 1; i += 2) {
    cout << m[v3[i]] << " " << m[v3[i + 1]] << endl;
    continue;
  }
}
```

Testcase

2

-32839949 -68986721 41592956

-32839949 -31435211 41592956

Comment: It is not really clear where in your code the problem is, the `, outside loop value of v3.size() is 0`  does not say at which point in your code this is the case. Also, the code itself does not make to much sense and I have absolutely no idea what the purpose fo the code should be.

Answer (score 3):

`v3` is empty when you get to the last loop. `v3.size()` is an unsigned value. So, you are using `0-1` as the upper loop bound, which (in unsigned arithmetic) is a huge value (2<sup>64</sup>-1 on 64 bit machines).

The simple fix is to not check for `i < v3.size() - 1` but for `i + 1 < v3.size()` as loop bound.

<sup>(The compiler does warn about comparing signed and unsigned values, but even if `i` was unsigned the problem would still occur. You just have to be careful with the corner cases when looping over less than a full container's size.)</sup>